# Python isinstance() returning error with datetime.date

Tags: python

I am trying to compile [an old 2008 code](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1151/).

```
import datetime

if isinstance(value, datetime.date):
```

But I got an error:

> isinstance() arg 2 must be a class,
>   type, or tuple of classes and types
>   Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python2.6
>   Python Version:   2.6.5

What am I missing?

Comment: `isinstance(1, datetime.date)` works and returns `False` in python 2.5.1 and 3.1.3.

Comment: try `print repr(datetime.date)` to find out what you are actually importing here. `isinstance(1, datetime.date)` returns `False` in python 2.6.1

Comment: I did the same test in 2.6.5 and it runs without error either. How can enforce that datetime.date is not a variable created with this name?

Comment: You can't really. Maybe your `datetime` isn't what you think it is? Try importing it and looking at `datetime.__file__`.

Answer (score 23):

I suspect you have imported the wrong datetime as in:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

instead use:

```
import datetime
```

Comment: On the contrary, this did fix it for me (python 3.3.5).

Comment: Actually, adding `from datetime import date` also fixed it, in case you used `from datetime import datetime`.

Answer (score 11):

To clarify this more, you must be careful if `datetime` is referring to the module from `import datetime` or the `datetime` class from `from datetime import datetime` as both have a `date` attribute.

In the first case, `datetime.date` refers to the date class which can be used with `isinstance`:

```
import datetime
type(datetime.date)
Out[13]: type
```

In the second case, the `datetime.date` refers to the date method of the datetime class which cannot be used with `isinstance` and hence the error.

```
from datetime import datetime
type(datetime.date)
Out[15]: method_descriptor
```

To help avoid errors like this it's best to explictly import and use the date class using `from datetime import date` then use `isinstance(value, date)`.

Answer (score 6):

I am running Python 2.7 and occasionally also ran into this error. Often simply checking the type will suffice if you do not need strict instance checking.

```
if id(type) and type(value) in (datetime.datetime, datetime.date):
   #somecode
```

Comment: Hey Lorenz from 2013, this is the distant future, the year 2018. Why do you check id(type)?