# Type of datetime object not returning 'True' as expected while using isinstance and type()

Tags: python, datetime, exception

I want to create a check for a parameter of a function to have only datetime arguments as strings!
So i was taking a string value and converting it to datetime.date object.. and check using isinstance or type is datetime.date..But it is not returning True as expected.. Can someone please help me in identifying the issue ?

Comment: Try to print `datetime.date`

Comment: @Guy I get <method 'date' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>

Comment: Does this look like the type of `date_object`?

Comment: Doing ``from datetime import datetime`` means the local name ``datetime`` refers to the ``datetime.datetime`` *class*, not its module.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Take a moment to revisit the [ask] page and [mre] help pages as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python isinstance() returning error with datetime.date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665597/python-isinstance-returning-error-with-datetime-date)

Comment: Yes.. It answers my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date_format = "%Y%m"
date_string = "202110"

import datetime

date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string,date_format).date()
print(date_object)
print(type(date_object))

print(type(date_object) is (datetime.date))
```

Importing datetime module this way solves the problem. Actually from datetime import datetime is ambiguous for python as it gets confused whether you are referring to the datetime module or the function. Importing it in the above way removes ambiguity. You can read more about it on a similar question posted at stackoverflow [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53215643/17948385)

Comment: If you found this helpful, then please accept it as a solution.

Comment: It looks like this answer points out that a different Q&A already solves this question. If this is the case, please flag or vote this question as a *duplicate* of the other Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the exact reason for this, converting it to a string somehow works.

```
str(type(date_obj)) == "<class 'datetime.date'>"
```

Returns

```
True
```